# SLAM Toolbox Mapping Issue?

Tags: slam, mapping, ros2, ros-humble

I am currently using ROS2 Humble and RP Lidar. I want to use SLAM with this so I am trying the Slam toolbox. So first I am doing: ros2 launch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch.py

Then in another terminal, I am doing: ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_async_launch.py

I don't have any urdf file, I just want to do static slam in RP lidar. I am getting the error:[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1679982623.449307761] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser' at time 1679982623.312 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'

Please help me or guide to do SLAM. My rqt graph is also attached for more informationRQT GraphOutput

I am expecting to do slam or its related projects in which we do mapping using lidar and SLAM

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the proper TF tree setup for this to work, so the node is telling you that its dropping data because it can't do anything with it. You need to provide laser scanner frame to base frame transforms and base frame to odometry frame transforms. This is covered well in documentation.